# Google Cloud Platform Visual Studio Publish

Tags: c#, firebase, google-cloud-platform

I have been deploying my C# MVC application for years now, as early as yesterday, successfully. Today however I started getting this error:

```
Step 6/6 : RUN npm install firebase-admin
 ---> Running in 6af72a3f9eaf
[91m/bin/sh: 1: npm: not found
The command '/bin/sh -c npm install firebase-admin' returned a non-zero code: 127
ERROR
ERROR: build step 0 "gcr.io/cloud-builders/docker" failed: step exited with non-zero status: 127
[0m
--------------------------------------------------------------------------------

ERROR: (gcloud.app.deploy) Cloud build failed. Check logs at https://console.cloud.google.com/cloud-build/builds/ea90f766-e252-4b9b-b707-746acf8ad686?project=186443889098 Failure status: UNKNOWN: Error Response: [2] Build failed; check build logs for details
Failed to deploy project [Project Name] to App Engine Flex.
```

The logs say this:

```
Step 6/6 : RUN npm install firebase-admin
 ---> Running in 6af72a3f9eaf
/bin/sh: 1: npm: not found
The command '/bin/sh -c npm install firebase-admin' returned a non-zero code: 127
ERROR
ERROR: build step 0 "gcr.io/cloud-builders/docker" failed: step exited with non-zero status: 127
```

Has anyone seen this error or know whats casing it?

Comment: The error message is generated by the shell not being able to find the program **npm**. https://cloud.google.com/build/docs/building/build-nodejs

Comment: @JohnHanley what would have changed over night to not be able to find npm? ` The public node image from Docker Hub comes preinstalled with npm and yarn tools` So shouldn't it be able to find it?

Comment: I do not know. Review the release history for the builder that you are using. Your question does not provide details but it appears you are using the Docker builder. That might be the wrong build image to use for .NET. https://github.com/GoogleCloudPlatform/cloud-builders In your case, modify your Dockerfile to install npm. How? That depends on which image you are basing your container upon.

Comment: as mentioned by @JohnHanley could you share your dockerfile so we can at least try to determine if the issue comes from within the image? Also take in account the suggestions of installing npm individually

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem was the node.js version was wrong. It was trying to use the wrong node version when publishing vs what was defined in the code.